# Passed executable path not obeyed by Windows START command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

In the Windows command prompt I run

```
"C:\foo.exe" file.asdf
```

Then foo.exe is opened.

However, if I run:

```
start "C:\foo.exe" file.asdf
```

Then bar.exe is opened.

bar.exe is defined as the default application associated with *.asdf files in Windows registry.

** Registry values:**

| Registry key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.asdf | APPLICATION.asdf |
| HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\APPLICATION.asdf\shell\open\command | "C:\bar.exe" "%1" |

Can someone please explain why this is the case and how I can make the start command run foo.exe without tampering the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `start` is technically closer to:

```
start [<title>] [<program> [<parameter>]]
```

So, a command like this will try and run `test.bat` with a window title of `notepad`:

```
start "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" test.bat
```

To open `test.bat` with notepad, give `start` a title to use:

```
start "notepad" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" test.bat
```

For more information about the syntax rules, check out the [Start](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) documentation.